# How to disable / re-map keyboard keys in the kernel?

Tags: linux, keyboard

I would like to remap my Caps Lock key to either nothing or a key code of my choice.

To get the same behaviour across different environments (X / Wayland / non-graphical TTYs), and for learning how to do things like that, it is important to do it at the kernel level (so `xmodmap`/`xkb` solutions will not help me).

How would I go about that?

Also, will a kernel module be sufficient or will it need to be a direct code change?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 10):

Neither kernel module nor kernel hack are necessary.

Using `setkeycodes` you can change the scancode to keycode translation mapping of the running kernel, requiring root privilege of course.

To map Caps Lock (scancode 0x3a) to say the key with the letter x (keycode 45) you would use `setkeycodes 3a 45` to give an example.

Using `showkey -s` and `showkey` you should be able to find needed scancode and keycode.

Be sure to issue given commands from the console not from a terminal.

Comment: AFAIK it does not works with USB keyboards: "USB keyboards have standardized keycodes and setkeycodes doesn't affect them at all. " https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=211803

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo setkeycodes 3a 45` just fails with `failed to set scancode 3a to keycode 45: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument` on Ubuntu 22.04.